# my browser cannot visit localhost after installing apache2 on termux

Tags: termux

my android browser cannot visit localhost after installing apache2 on termux.
How do i access the server by visiting localhost?
I hage tried restarting the phone but no change

Comment: have you seen this https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1316